# How to export & import only data in oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I want to export only data on of my master tables and then imports it to some other server on same oracle 11g . Is it possible to do that. using exp command it dumps the complete data along with schema which I don`t want . I want only data to be dump and imported to some other location.

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't with the [original export (`exp`) utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE), but with the newer data pump `expdp` you can use the [`content` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#sthref61) to export only the data:

```
expdp content=data_only ...
```

With `exp` I think the closest equivalent is to set [`ignore=y`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#sthref2201) on import; it will try to recreate the schema objects but won't complain that they're already there. But since the original utilities are deprecated, you should use data pump anyway.

Comment: but it didn`t worked.. I tried exp with specific table names and while importing I used imp and with options DATA_ONLY=Y. It solved my issue.